# NoMethodError while adding node in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I am trying to print a linked list in ruby but getting the error add': undefined method `next=' for #<Node:0x000001c5c0738688 @data=1, @next=nil> (NoMethodError)
any idea what i should do ?

```
class Node
    def initialize data
        @data = data
        @next = nil
    end
end

class LinkedList
    def initialize
        @head = nil
    end
    def add data
        temp = @head
        @head = Node.new(data)
        @head.next = temp
    end
    def printList
        temp = @head
        while temp
            puts temp.data
            temp = temp.next
        end
    end
end

list = LinkedList.new
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)

list.printList()
```

Comment: The error message pinpoints the reason for the exception: there is no instance method `Node#next=` (called a *setter*). You can create one as follows: `class Node; def node=(n); @node=n; end; end`. The conventional way of doing that is to let Ruby create the setter when the class is created by adding the line `attr_writer :node` (or  `attr_writer(:node)`) to the class definition. [Module::attr_writter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) is a *class method*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the setter for the `next` attribute I'd propose adding an attribute_accessor to `Node`.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :next

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

This will generate both a `setter` and a `getter` for the next attribute within your `Node` instance.

Additionally I would also add an `attr_reader` to `Node` so that you can access `data` from outside of the instance.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :next
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```